# IN OR multiple operator SAP Java

Tags: java, sap-erp, jco

I am creating a query using JCO, SAP util for the following code for example:

```
public static void TEST() throws JCoException {
            JCoDestination destination;
            JCoRepository sapRepository;

            destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(ABAP_AS);
            JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(ABAP_AS);
            System.out.println("Attributes:");
            System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());
            System.out.println();

            try {
                JCoContext.begin(destination);
                sapRepository = destination.getRepository();

                if (sapRepository == null) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't get repository!");
                    System.exit(0);
                } 
                JCoFunctionTemplate functionTemplate = sapRepository.getFunctionTemplate("EM_GET_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES");
                JCoFunction function =  functionTemplate.getFunction();
                JCoTable itTable = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("IT_TABLES");
                itTable.appendRow();

                itTable.setValue("TABNAME", "USR02");
//              JCoTable returnOptions_ = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("OPTIONS");
//              returnOptions_.appendRow();
////                //returnOptions.setValue("TEXT", "MODDA GE '20140908' AND MODTI GT '000000'");
//              returnOptions_.setValue("TEXT", "BNAME EQ 'USER'");
                function.execute(destination);
                System.out.println( function.getTableParameterList().getTable("IT_TABLES").getInt("TABROWS"));
                JCoFunctionTemplate template2 = sapRepository.getFunctionTemplate("RFC_READ_TABLE");
                System.out.println("Getting template");
                JCoFunction function2 = template2.getFunction();
                function2.getImportParameterList().setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "USR02");
                function2.getImportParameterList().setValue("DELIMITER", ",");
                function2.getImportParameterList().setValue( "ROWCOUNT",5);
                function2.getImportParameterList().setValue( "ROWSKIPS",5);



                System.out.println("Setting OPTIONS");
//              Date date = new Date(1410152400000L);
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
//              String dateString = formatter.format(date);

//              String dt = dateString.substring(0, 8);
//              String tm = dateString.substring(8);
//              System.out.println("dt > " + dt + ", tm > " + tm);

                JCoTable returnOptions = function2.getTableParameterList().getTable("OPTIONS");
                returnOptions.appendRow();
                //returnOptions.setValue("TEXT", "MODDA GE '20140908' AND MODTI GT '000000'");
                returnOptions.setValue("TEXT", "BNAME LIKE 'S%'");

//              returnOptions.appendRow();
//              returnOptions.setValue("TEXT", "AND TYPE = 'DN'");

                System.out.println("Setting FIELDS");
                JCoTable returnFields = function2.getTableParameterList().getTable("FIELDS");
                returnFields.appendRow();
                returnFields.setValue("FIELDNAME", "BNAME");
                returnFields.appendRow();
                returnFields.setValue("FIELDNAME", "GLTGB");
                returnFields.appendRow();
                returnFields.setValue("FIELDNAME", "CLASS");
//              returnFields.appendRow();
                function2.execute(destination);

//              JCoTable jcoTablef = function2.getTableParameterList().getTable("FIELDS");
                JCoTable jcoTabled = function2.getTableParameterList().getTable("DATA");

                int icodeOffSet = 0;
                int icodeLength = 0;


                int numRows = jcoTabled.getNumRows();
                System.out.println("numRows > " + numRows);
                for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
                    jcoTabled.setRow(i);
                    System.out.println(jcoTabled.getRow());
                    String BNAME = "BNAE:" +  jcoTabled.getString(0);
//                  String GLTGB = "GLTGB:" + jcoTabled.getString(2);
//                  String cls = "GLTGB:" + jcoTabled.getString(3);
                    System.out.println(BNAME + "..." );
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());   
            } finally {
                JCoContext.end(destination);
            }
        }
        static void createDestinationDataFile(String destinationName, Properties connectProperties)
        {
            File destCfg = new File(destinationName+".jcoDestination");
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destCfg, false);
                connectProperties.store(fos, "for tests only !");
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create the destination files", e);
            }
        }
```

The previous code worked well when I used the EQ operator.
However, when I used the IN operator:

```
BNAME IN ('USER1','USER','USER3')
```

or

```
BNAME EQ 'USER1' OR BNAME EQ 'USER' OR BNAME EQ 'USER3'
```

It throws an exception: `Unexpected dynamic condition`

Are there any limitations to the condition size? Since I have 22 field in the IN condition and each value has a size of 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a [valid OpenSQL condition](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenwhere_logexp.htm), you need to observe the [rules for dynamic conditions](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenwhere_logexp_dynamic.htm) and you need to ensure that the condition is properly split into lines of 72 characters. My guess would be that the last bit might have been an issue if you're specifying 22 conditions...